# iMessage App crashing if i duoble tap on stickers in expanded view and press send button

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10, imessage, imessage-extension

I am following this tutorial to create an app using iMessage Extension :

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-imessage-app-in-ios-10--cms-26870

Issue is: When I open Expanded View and then double tap on any sticker,While transition from expended to compact view, Bottom bar got crashed.

I have seen few iMessage app on appstore, in few of them click on expanded view is disabled while in some of them its properly working.

If anyone has worked on this and solved this issue. Provide some suggestions how to resolve this issue.